# Django and simple Ajax w/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I've met a huge problem with my django. I just want to call a view when document is ready and pass a value back to js and its alert function:
I've read a lot of here stack's solutions, some articles, jquery docs, implemented a lot of samples - nothing worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("/resultlive/", function(response) {
            //$( ".loading-progress-6" ).css( 'width: ' response );
            alert(response);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

and the resultlive view is:

```
def resultlive(request):
  task = Task.objects.get(id=1)
  data= task.done
  json_data = json.dumps(data)
  return HttpResponse(json_data, mimetype='application/json')
```

where work-progress is simple (and only):

```
{{percentageDone}}
```

on localhost/resultlive I am getting proper result
but on the whole template-page console says: error 500 internal server error with jquery.extend

What I need to do? I need to automatically refresh the task done value and change the width of progress bar without refreshing a webpage

I spent 5 hours and nothing worked, please for some suggestions for jquery very newbie

**EDIT:**

Okay, I've done new Sample project specially to test responses, I've got view with func:

```
def ajax(request):
   pcs = Workstation.objects.get(id=1)
   response_data = {}
   try:
       response_data['result'] = 'Success'
       response_data['message'] = list(pcs)
   except:
       response_data['result'] = 'Fail'
       response_data['message'] = 'fail'
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

and JavaScript call after href click:

```
        <script type = 'text/javascript'>
            function FireScript(){
                $.ajax({type:'GET', url: '/ajax/', datatype: 'json', async: true, data: {},
                        success: function(json) {alert(json.message);}
                });
            }

        </script>
```

And it does work well, but when I change in view:
    response_data['message'] = list(pcs) 
       changed to:
    response_data['message'] = pcs.processes_done

Console throws error 500, why?
at Python it works very well.

**EDIT2:**

This one guy retrieves only one row (as expected) and returns two vars to view by using AJAX, gosh... finally

```
def ajax(request):
   pcs = Workstation.objects.get(id=1)
   response_data = {}
   try:
      response_data['result'] = 'Success'
      response_data['message'] = str(pcs.processes_made)
      #serializers.serialize("json", pcs) for more objects
   except:
     response_data['result'] = 'Fail'
     response_data['message'] = 'fail'

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: What happens if you try to `print json_data` before you return it?  What does e.g. firebug say is coming from the server?  Are you using a traffic debugging tool like e.g. Fiddler2?

Comment: No i can't debug anything in django except saving args to text files. Tt's my first tome with js. When i was making checks in django resultlive view if the request is get or ajax they wasn't

Comment: In your developer tools (chrome) or firebug (firefox), what does the 500 return as error?

Comment: Please see EDIT section :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your AJAX view:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def ajax(request):
   pcs = Workstation.objects.get(id=1)
   response_data = {}
   try:
       response_data['result'] = 'Success'
       response_data['message'] = list(pcs)
   except:
       response_data['result'] = 'Fail'
       response_data['message'] = 'fail'
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

---

The only change I add is the `@csrf_exempt` and the import of csrf_exempt `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

You could check [Django Cross Site Protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax). Is Django documentation about cross site protection and csrf tokens.

Comment: I was avoiding this to simplify the code. After adding this nothing changed - with message as list(pcs) it works, but when message is just a simple integer I'm getting: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Comment: I know this is useless but if you do `response_data['message'] = str(pcs.processes_done)` or `response_data['message'] = list(pcs.processes_done)` instead of `response_data['message'] = pcs.processes_done` you got same error almost sure, dont you ?

Comment: Yes, I was having the same error BUT I've found that django returns that my model is not JSON serializable, so I've used serializers.serialize("json", pcs) and it works, but output is not satisfying: http://pastebin.com/xnEA9Wpa

Comment: ok, with your help I've got finally needed result, thx and see EDIT2 :)

Comment: You're welcome! It's nice to help. I've been there and AJAX could be very anoying...

Comment: I have one little, tiny question more: when I pass serializable list of objects, how can I access from JS to a value of the second object. Please look at pastebin link again, how to retrieve the value of processes_done of Computer 2 from this response?

Comment: Can't see processes_done in any of the raw data in pastebin, you mean processes_made? Anyway in the JS function you should do something like `parsed_response = JSON.parse(response);` to parse from json to normal dict and then `parsed_response['message']` or `parsed_response['result']`